# Change file:// protocal to http:// protocol in Android Ionic application

Tags: android, ionic3

I am developing a mobile app using **Ionic 3.2** for both IOS and Android platforms. I am trying to load an external web page into an Iframe in the app. I made changes to CSP headers of the external web page, now page allows to load in localhost:8080 origins.

The app is able to load the external page successfully in IOS. IOS serves the index.html page using HTTP:// protocol. Same app failing to load on Android.

BTW Android serves the index.html through file:// protocol.

How I can change **file://** protocol to **http://** protocol in Android app?

Where do I need to make changes?